# Inserting an object from a vector to a list of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, containers

I'm attempting to push back an object from a vector to a list of pointers. Unfortunatelly, my method doesn't work properly.

```
list<CStudent*> averageparam(const int a, const int b)
{
    list<CStudent*> l;
    vector<CStudent>::iterator itt;
    for (itt=students.begin();itt!=students.end();itt++)
        if((*itt).average() >= a && (*itt).average() <= b)
            l.push_back(*itt);
    return l;
}
```

This is the error that I'm receiving on line `l.push_back(*itt)`

```
no matching function for call to 'std::list<CStudent*>::push_back(CStudent&)'".
```

If I'm not mistaken, I'll need to call the print method in the main function as `(*it)->print()`, but I don't know how to insert the objects from the vector into the list of pointers.

Here is the code in the main function, which calls this method.

```
list<CStudent*> l;
a=50, b=60;
for (it=uni.begin();it!=uni.end();it++)
{
    l = (*it).averageparam(a,b);
    if (l.empty())
        cout<<"There are no students in spec."<<(*it).getspec()<<" course "<<(*it).getkurs()<<" group "<<(*it).getgrupa()<<" with average amount of points between "<<a<<" - "<<b<<endl<<endl;
    else
    {
        cout<<"Students in spec."<<(*it).getspec()<<" course "<<(*it).getkurs()<<" group "<<(*it).getgrupa()<<" with average amount of points between "<<a<<" - "<<b<<endl;
        list<CStudent>::iterator it=l.begin();
        for (it=l.begin();it!=l.end();it++)
            (*it).print();
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "doesn't work properly" means?

Comment: This is the error that I'm receiving on line l.push_back(*itt) " no matching function for call to 'std::list<CStudent*>::push_back(CStudent&)'". If I'm not mistaken, I'll need to call the print method in the main function as (*it)->print(), but I don't know how to insert the objects from the vector into the list of pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
l.push_back(*itt);
```

Is passing a `CStudent&`, while the `l` only receives `CStudent*`. Changing that line to

```
l.push_back(&*itt);
```

Will instead pass the address (pointer to) the stored `CStudent`items.